# MVVM with Caliburn.micro - Populating a Datagrid control with a bindable collection

Tags: wpf, mvvm, data-binding, datagrid, caliburn.micro

I am attempting to resolve a deadlock where I am unable to view a bindable collection in a datagrid.  This is part of my efforts to learn MVVM.  The MVVM framework uses Caliburn Micro and a separate class library project in the same solution connects to local SQL database using Dapper.  The code for the ShellView and ShellViewModel are pasted below

**ShellView - XAML**

```
<Window x:Class="WPFUI.Views.ShellView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPFUI.Views"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="ShellView" Height="450" Width="800" Background="Red">
    <Grid>

        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="100" Height="50" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <Button x:Name="LoadCHARecRatesList" Content="CHA Rec Rates"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=LstCHARecModels, Mode=OneWay}" Margin="20,100,20,30" AutoGenerateColumns="True">

        </DataGrid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The ShellViewModel code is as follows:

**ShellViewModel**

```
public class ShellViewModel : Conductor<object>
    {
        private BindableCollection<CHARecModel> _lstcharecmodels;

        public BindableCollection<CHARecModel> LstCHARecModels
        {
            get
            {return _lstcharecmodels;}

            set
            {
                _lstcharecmodels = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => LstCHARecModels);
            }
        }

        public void LoadCHARecRatesList()
        {
            var data = LoadReviewRCRRatesTbl();
            _lstcharecmodels = new BindableCollection<CHARecModel>();

            foreach (var row in data)
            {
                _lstcharecmodels.Add(new CHARecModel
                {
                    TDate = row.TDate,
                    Vendor = row.Vendor,
                    Code=row.Code,
                    NameCode=row.NameCode,
                    Price = row.Price,
                    RCRStatus=row.RCRStatus,
                    NameCodeDate = row.NameCodeDate

                });


            }

        }

    }
```

The button on the ShellView is wired up to the `LoadCHARecRatesList` method (which sits in a different class library responsible for dataaccess and the output of this method populates the bindable collection `LstCHARecModels`) and the Datagrid is bound to a bindable collection `LstCHARecModels` - the bindable collection is notifying property changes.  The intention is that when the button is clicked on the UI, it will fetch data from the SQL database and populate the datagrid.  The problem Im unable to solve is that the Datagrid remains blank.  When I run the code by placing a break on the last line of the of the `LoadCHARecRatesList` method, I note that the collection (`LstCHARecModels` ) is being accurately populated in the ShellViewModel.  When I hover the mouse over the `LstCHARecModels` in the following line 
            `<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=LstCHARecModels, Mode=OneWay}" Margin="20,100,20,30" AutoGenerateColumns="True">` in the ShellView I note that the collection has bubbled up into the Datagrid definition (I can see all the elements and can drill into each element to view the data within - I note that its accurate in both the count of elements as well as the contents of each element).  But even after this, when I run the project, the datagrid remains **totally blank**.

**Other attempts**

While defining the Datagrid I have also attempted ````x:Name="LstCHARecModels"````` to no avail.

I am requesting assistance on how I can get the bindablecollection to populate the datagrid.  Essentially, it beggars belief that the `LstCHARecModels` can be viewed in the binding of the datagrid in debug mode, but even after coming so close, the datagrid does not get populated!

Comment: **Edit** Experimenting to find a solution has revealed that copying the code within the method ````LoadCHARecRatesList```` and pasting it into the ````ShellViewModel```` constructor populates the datagrid.  But trying to achieve the same result away from the construtor method by triggering it through a button click gets the bindablecollection to the ShellView - but it doesnt populate the DataGrid.  Curiouser and curiouser...

Answer (score 0):

change your code by calling the public and not private property:

```
    public void LoadCHARecRatesList()
    {
        var data = LoadReviewRCRRatesTbl();
        LstCHARecModels = new BindableCollection<CHARecModel>();

        foreach (var row in data)
        {
            LstCHARecModels.Add(new CHARecModel
            {
                TDate = row.TDate,
                Vendor = row.Vendor,
                Code=row.Code,
                NameCode=row.NameCode,
                Price = row.Price,
                RCRStatus=row.RCRStatus,
                NameCodeDate = row.NameCodeDate

            });

        }
    }
```

another thing, have you need to Conductor.. i dunno the code you are using, but screen will be sufficent...

Comment: Thanks @Frenchy.  Happy to try out what you are suggesting.  Also, regarding your observation on Conductor.  I am new to MVVM.  I understand that Conductor is used when you have different screens.  What I have posted is one section of my code (that I was struggling with).  The entire application has multiple screens - and for this reason, I have chosen conductor.  Knowing what you now do, would you believe I have still erred in my approach?  Thanks a lot for your help again

Comment: no you dont erred with this approach, i dont know how its built your project..if you pilot multiscreen, yes its good thing..i suppose you have read https://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/composition

Comment: Thanks again Frenchy.  I actually follow a Vlog on YouTube on which my learning is based on.  It was explained in the same that Conductor<object> is the way to go for multiscreen projects.  The documentation for Caliburn is just painful to go through - or maybe its just me!

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize the `BindableCollection<CHARecModel>` *once* and then add items to it in your method:

```
public class ShellViewModel : Conductor<object>
{
    private BindableCollection<CHARecModel> _lstcharecmodels = new BindableCollection<CHARecModel>();
    public BindableCollection<CHARecModel> LstCHARecModels
    {
        get { return _lstcharecmodels; }
    }

    public void LoadCHARecRatesList()
    {
        var data = LoadReviewRCRRatesTbl();
        foreach (var row in data)
        {
            _lstcharecmodels.Add(new CHARecModel
            {
                TDate = row.TDate,
                Vendor = row.Vendor,
                Code = row.Code,
                NameCode = row.NameCode,
                Price = row.Price,
                RCRStatus = row.RCRStatus,
                NameCodeDate = row.NameCodeDate

            });
        }
    }
}
```

If you create a new collection each time the method is called, it's kind of pointless to use a `BindableCollection<T>`.

Provided that you raise the `PropertyChanged` event in the setter, it should still work if you set the *property* instead of the backing field:

```
public void LoadCHARecRatesList()
{
    var data = LoadReviewRCRRatesTbl();
    LstCHARecModels = new BindableCollection<CHARecModel>();

    foreach (var row in data)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks MM8.  Your response is both clear and concise.  Im curious to understand better your point regarding it being pointless to create bindable collection if I create it everytime the method is called.  The method ultimately pulls out data from a multi user SQL - which more or less necessitated the creation of the Bindable collection for each method call.  To not do so, would mean risking the user seeing stale data even within the same session.  Please let me if I have still missed your point - or does this make sense to you.  Thanks again for your time and assistance

Comment: If you create a new collection each time, you might as well use a `List<T>`. That's what I meant.

Comment: Aah ok! I learn something new.... in my naivete I had assumed that using a List would not bind it to the datagrid.  Thanks for correcting an impression which I probably would not have felt the need to revisit ..... As both my question as well as subsequent comments would have revealed, Im a noob trying to pick up WPF, MVVM and caliburn micro - needless to add the learning curve has been significant steep! Thank you very much for your time and help.  Much appreciated!

Comment: @MangéshMéhendalé: Did you try this or what happened?